# How to add queries between tables in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, multi-tenant

I'm trying to design a complicated form. Fields also need to add data that I received with queries to other tables.

Here's what I'm trying to do.

Rad_check form is composed of username and password... When the user registers by typing username and password, the Rad_cheks table must consist of other records in the back. I was able to do some of the Radcheck model. However, I want to conditionally query the tenant_id column in the Nas table and insert it into the Rad_checks table. I've actually prepared a query for that, but I don't know how to use it.

Na.select(:tenant_id).where(Na.arel_table[:realipaddr].eq('form's real ip will be'))

Actually, I'm using the Milia gem file. However, there will be a somewhat more public form... the query I created must come in a way instead of the IP address of the request. REMOTE_IP code. This means that the user's actual IP address is tenant_id information that is equal to the IP address in the NAS table.

When saving the Rad_chek form, I want to query the user's actual IP address in the Nas table and add the tenant_id number of the equal data to the Rad_cheks table. How can I do that?

Help me! Please

TABLE

```
class CreateRadChecks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :rad_checks do |t|
      t.integer :tenant_id
      t.string :username
      t.string :password
      t.string :attribu
      t.string :op

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

FORM

```
<%= form_with(model: rad_check, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if rad_check.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(rad_check.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this rad_check from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% rad_check.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :username %>
    <%= form.text_field :username %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :password %>
    <%= form.text_field :password %>
  </div>  

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

MODEL

```
class RadCheck < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :rad_user_group, dependent: :destroy

    after_initialize :add_rad_user_group
    before_save :set_radcheck   

    def add_rad_user_group
      self.rad_user_group ||= RadUserGroup.new if self.new_record?
    end 


    def set_radcheck
      self.rad_user_group.username = username
      self.op = ":="
      self.attribu = "Cleartext-Password"
    end
end
```

rad_user_group table

```
class CreateRadUserGroups < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :rad_user_groups do |t|
      t.integer :tenant_id
      t.string :username
      t.string :groupname
      t.references :rad_check, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

nas table

```
class CreateNas < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :nas do |t|
      t.integer :tenant_id
      t.string :nasname
      t.string :realipaddr
      t.boolean :active

    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Rad_check form is composed of username and password... When the user registers by typing username and password, the Rad_cheks table must consist of other records in the back. I was able to do some of the Radcheck model. However, I want to conditionally query the tenant_id column in the Nas table and insert it into the Rad_checks table. I've actually prepared a query for that, but I don't know how to use it. Na.select (: tenant_id) .name (Na.arel_table [: realipaddr] .eq ('formun gerçek ipi' olacaktır))   How do I add this query to the teanat_id arm when saving a form?

Comment: When saving the Rad_chek form, I want to query the user's actual IP address in the Nas table and add the tenant_id number of the equal data to the Rad_cheks table. How can I do that?

Comment: You should add the controller action where this is happening as well as the params as submitted by your form.

Comment: How can I add a params to such a query. Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming:

- You have a variable called `realipaddr`
- Nas belongs_to :tenant
- RadCheck belongs_to :tenant
- you have instantiated a variable called `@rad_check`

Then you should be able to do something like:

```
@rad_check.update(tenant: Nas.find_by(realipaddr: realipaddr).tenant)
```

Or, if you don't want the `save` that occurs with `update`:

```
@rad_check.tenant = Nas.find_by(realipaddr: realipaddr).tenant
```

If you're instantiating `@rad_check` based on `rad_check_params` in a controller, you might do something like:

```
def create
  @rad_check = RadCheck.new(rad_check_params)
  if @rad_check.save
    # do something
  else
    # do something else 
  end
end

def rad_check_params
  params.require(:rad_check).permit(:some, :parameters).merge!(tenant: nas_tenant))
end 

def nas_tenant
  Nas.find_by(realipaddr: realipaddr).tenant
end
```

There are probably other ways, too.

Comment: That's how it worked. I really appreciate the information you gave me. Only the variable request.remote_ip returns the local IP address. The ISP does not give the IP address. How do I make this?

Answer (score 0):

That's how it worked. I really appreciate the information you gave me. Only the variable request.remote_ip returns the local IP address. The ISP does not give the IP address. How do I make this?

```
def realipaddr
    request.remote_addr
  end
  # POST /rad_checks
  # POST /rad_checks.json
  def create
    @rad_check = RadCheck.new(rad_check_params)
    @rad_check.tenant_id = Na.find_by(realipaddr: realipaddr).tenant_id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @rad_check.save
        format.html { redirect_to @rad_check, notice: 'Rad check was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @rad_check }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @rad_check.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: If you have your associations set up correctly, you should be able to do `@rad_check.tenant = Na.find_by(realipaddr: realipaddr).tenant` (without `_id`).